# Using XPATH with Walmart.com Tables

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to select information from Walmart.com's product tables. Walmart formats their tables as follows:

```
<tr>    
<td class="display-name" colspan="1" rowspan="1">Assembled Product Dimensions (L x W x H)</td>
<td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
<div>3.90 x 5.60 x 10.20 Inches</div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Using this XPATH:

```
//td[contains(@class, 'display-name') and text ()='Assembled Product Dimensions (L x W x H)']
```

I am able to reliably find the first TD, but I cant figure out how to return the actual product dimensions. For example, I want my XPATH to return:

```
3.90 x 5.60 x 10.20 Inches
```

instead of

```
Assembled Product Dimensions (L x W x H)
```

I have tried some following-sibling combinations but haven't been successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `/../td/div` to the end of your XPath, so that the whole expression looks like

```
//td[contains(@class, 'display-name') and text ()='Assembled Product Dimensions (L x W x H)']/../td/div
```